# Accessing variables from tf.while_loop() that is not an iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I need to run a loop where I use the iterator only for the bound and access the result of the loop afterwards.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def add(h_tl):
    res = tf.add(h_tl, tf.constant(1, shape=[2,1]))
    return res

x = tf.constant(5)  # iterator for while loop
h_tl = tf.constant(0, shape=[2,1])
H_l = tf.constant(0, shape=[2,1])
def body(x):  # Body of loop
    global H_l
    global h_tl  # I need to use H_l and h_tl in the body of the loop
    h_tl = add(h_tl)  # Some simple modifications to h_tl which will be added to H_l
    H_l = tf.concat([H_l, h_tl], 1)
    # I want the result of H_l after the loop and use it for further calculations
    return (x+1)

def condition(x):  # Stop condition
    return x < tf.constant(10)

y = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [x])
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(y))
print(sess.run(H_l))  # Result of the loop
sess.close()
```

So, I want to do calculations on H_l which is done for every x between 5 and 10. How do I access the end result of H_l after the loop is completed? When I run x I get the correct value of 10, but when I try to run H_l I get the following error: "Operation 'while/concat' has been marked as not fetchable."

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow while loops are designed to allow different iterations to be run in parallel. This causes them to behave rather differently from what you'd expect coming from other programming languages.

One such oddity is that if you create a tensor inside the loop, you cannot access it from outside. In your case, you are creating a new tensor with every `tf.concat` op. Yes, even though that tensor is stored under the same Python variable name as the previous version, it is still a new tensor: indeed, the original `H_l` is a constant, so its value cannot be changed; you can only create a new tensor in its place. The same is true for `h_tl`.

To solve this problem for `H_l`, what you want is to store an array of tensors, and add another entry to this array at each iteration. The data structure for doing this is [`tf.TensorArray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray), which you should initialize outside the loop and then write into at each iteration.

For `h_tl`, in which you only want to examine the final value, you don't need a `tf.TensorArray`; you could use a `tf.Variable` instead, and use `tf.assign` to update its value.

In both cases, take care to ensure that the mutating ops are executed, by including them in a [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) block.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but it doesn't work yet. Do I have to give `H_l` to the loop such that `[x]`, becomes `[x, H_l]`? Also, I need to convert the whole TensorArray to a 2D tensor that will be used for further calculations.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To convert the TensorArray to a 2D tensor after you've closed it, use `tensor_array.stack()`.